# Tests process terminates when running in parallel in jest - "A worker process has quit unexpectedly!"

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

My jest Tests fail when running in parallel in jest.

When I try and run

```
jest
```

From my project root I get the following error and the test process terminates.

"A worker process has quit unexpectedly!"

I am using jest 19.0.2 and node 6.9.4. I have also tried other combinations of node 7.7.2 and jest 19.0 which didn't work either.

[image]

Note that when I run my tests sequentially using

```
jest --runInBand
```

My tests work fine. Although since they are not running in parallel they are slower which is not ideal.

My tests launch the same server for each new test so perhaps running parallel means that multiple tests are trying to launch the server on a port where it is already running.

[image]

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "6.5.1",
    "babel-core": "6.17.0",
    "babel-eslint": "7.1.1",
    "babel-jest": "17.0.2",
    "babel-loader": "6.2.7",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^2.0.1",
    "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "1.1.4",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "chai-as-promised": "^6.0.0",
    "chalk": "1.1.3",
    "connect-history-api-fallback": "1.3.0",
    "cross-spawn": "4.0.2",
    "css-loader": "0.26.0",
    "detect-port": "1.0.1",
    "dotenv": "2.0.0",
    "eslint": "3.8.1",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^0.5.0",
    "eslint-loader": "1.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "2.21.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "2.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "6.4.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "1.0.1",
    "file-loader": "0.9.0",
    "filesize": "3.3.0",
    "fs-extra": "0.30.0",
    "gzip-size": "3.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "2.24.0",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "0.17.2",
    "jest": "^19.0.2",
    "jest-css-modules": "^1.1.0",
    "json-loader": "0.5.4",
    "object-assign": "4.1.0",
    "path-exists": "2.1.0",
    "postcss-loader": "1.0.0",
    "promise": "7.1.1",
    "react-dev-utils": "^0.4.2",
    "recursive-readdir": "2.1.0",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.2.2",
    "sinon": "^1.17.7",
    "strip-ansi": "3.0.1",
    "style-loader": "0.13.1",
    "supertest": "^3.0.0",
    "url-loader": "0.5.7",
    "webpack": "1.14.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "1.16.2",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "1.1.0",
    "whatwg-fetch": "1.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.15.3",
    "bcrypt-nodejs": "0.0.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.16.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.1",
    "eventemitter2": "^3.0.1",
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "jwt-simple": "^0.5.1",
    "mocha": "^3.2.0",
    "mongoose": "^4.7.8",
    "morgan": "^1.7.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.11.0",
    "passport": "^0.3.2",
    "passport-jwt": "^2.2.1",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.2",
    "react-router": "^3.0.2",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.0",
    "redux-form": "^5.3.3",
    "redux-socket.io": "^1.3.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^1.7.3",
    "socketio-auth": "^0.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node scripts/start.js",
    "build": "node scripts/build.js",
    "test": "jest --runInBand"
  },
  "jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx}"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [
      "<rootDir>/config/polyfills.js"
    ],
    "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
      "<rootDir>[/\\\\](build|docs|node_modules)[/\\\\]"
    ],
    "testEnvironment": "jest-environment-jsdom",
    "testURL": "http://localhost",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js|jsx)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/jest-css-modules"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx)$"
    ],
    "verbose": true,
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^react-native$": "react-native-web"
    }
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "react-app"
    ]
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try adding this flag to the jest CLI command:

```
jest --env=jsdom --runInBand
```

from the Jest API docs

http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/cli.html#env-environment